# Touchpad detected properly but does not function Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, 15.10

I'm relatively new to linux so I apologize if this ends up being a simple answer.

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 3452 laptop that is running Ubuntu 15.10. So far I have everything working except the touchpad. I have followed several forum and wiki posts trying to figure out the problem but still have not managed to get the touchpad working. From what I can tell it is detected and enabled but I get no functionality at all and have to use an external USB mouse.

cat /proc/bus/input/devices returns the following relevant device:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01a1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 610000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

Xorg.0.log contains the following lines:

```
[    23.993] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL06AC:00      06CB:78F1 (/dev/input/event12)
[    23.993] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[    23.993] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[    23.993] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[    23.993] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    23.993] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    23.997] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.997]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.8.2
[    23.997]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    23.997]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    23.997] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1'
[    23.997] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: always reports core events
[    23.997] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event12"
[    24.033] (II) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: found clickpad property
[    24.033] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: x-axis range 1 - 2040 (res 19)
[    24.033] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: y-axis range 1 - 1240 (res 19)
[    24.034] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: pressure range 0 - 255
[    24.034] (II) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: device does not report finger width.
[    24.034] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: buttons: left double triple
[    24.034] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x78f1
[    24.034] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: invalid finger width range.  defaulting to 0 - 15
[    24.034] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[    24.034] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: touchpad found
[    24.034] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: always reports core events
[    24.052] (**) Option "config_info"   "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:00/i2c-9/i2c-DLL06AC:00/0018:06CB:78F1.0001/input/input14/event12"
[    24.052] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[    24.053] (**) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    24.053] (**) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    24.053] (**) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.084
[    24.053] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    24.053] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[    24.053] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    24.053] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    24.055] (--) synaptics: DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: touchpad found
[    24.056] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    24.056] (**) DLL06AC:00 06CB:78F1: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
```

syclient -l returns:

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 1625
RightEdge               = 5359
TopEdge                 = 1482
BottomEdge              = 4458
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 244
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 111
HorizScrollDelta        = 111
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.036036
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 27
VertHysteresis          = 27
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3492
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 4077
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

I appreciate any help getting this up and running. One other side note. The touchpad will sometimes stop getting detected after resuming from sleep and the system shows a Generic P/S 2 mouse instead. The only way I can tell right now is by running the above commands but I thought that could be a relevant detail.

Comment: There is a bug report, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521972, filed for a different Dell computer with the same problem.  I have the same computer and the same problem that you do.